# Can we nuke spam/hate answers from orbit, instead of just marking them as deleted?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, etiquette, spam

Every now and again, some troll comes along and posts a answer like:

> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`> I hate xxx, xxx is <`insert profanity here`>.

These answers get deleted fast, but...
Having 20k+ rep, I have to look at this nonsense.

[image]

Is there an option to permanently/hard delete hate answers posts, so they go away, or must we look at them for all eternity?

**Option 1: hard delete**
Note that I'm not asking for automated tools, but moderators should have the option to nuke a post **only if it's entirely free of any informational content whatsoever**

**Option 2: allow moderators to edit a deleted post**
As per David's suggestion, an option to allow moderators to edit a hate post would fix the problem whilst leaving an audit trail, something like:

[image]

This option has the advantage that the problem is solved, but nothing is permanently erased, because the `edit history` is still there in case you want to check what all the fuss is about.

## Update

Fixed in build (rev 2013.10.8.1061).

Comment: Easy solution: give away your rep via bounties! Problem solved!

Comment: You don't see them in the lists when they get refreshed. Would be the same with nuked posts.

Comment: Run for moderator, get elected, nuke from orbit.

Comment: @Oded: But then he has to look at them too :)

Comment: Wondering how you would distinguish these from other deleted answers...? In an automated way?

Comment: So, essentially you are asking for a hard delete option.

Comment: Which will never happen, I hope.

Comment: @juergend, do you mean they disappear? because that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Oded, yes exactly

Comment: When they get deleted they disappear from question lists (like "newest questions"). You have to refresh the list.

Comment: @juergend - As a +10k user, when you go to a question, you see all deleted answers as well (though with a highlight and at the bottom). I believe the OP wants to not see this kind of deleted post, ever.

Comment: @Oded: Oh, I see. I did not come accross hate **answers** very often if ever...

Comment: @juergend - They are not common. And deleted items are only visible to a tiny number of users, so... not sure if this will ever get implemented.

Comment: @Oded The tiny number of users are also the ones that visit the site the most and have a disproportionate number of page views.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - sure. And I appreciate where you are coming from, after yesterday's occurrences.

Comment: @Johan - Option 2 is already there. 10k+ users can edit [deleted posts too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17939097/1369235).

Comment: Cool, I did not know (or realize).

Comment: Please don't flag the deleted posts as "offensive" or "spam". If you can see them you can edit them.

Comment: @Oded, thanks for the cleanup

Comment: @Johan - Chris did a bunch as well.

Comment: Thanks @Oded and ChrisF and the other moderators for deleting and cleaning up. I do appreciate your work here.

Comment: What about just hiding it? (click on a link and it will be shown). Or a "I don't want to see deleted content" mode?

Comment: @Oded I think this can now be marked [meta-tag:status-completed] as well, with spam hidden away safely. :)

Comment: Deleted answers that have been marked as spam/offensive [are hidden now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199859/is-there-any-means-by-which-offensive-spam-can-be-removed-even-after-deletion).

Comment: Give me your rep. Problem solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion this nuking option would be easy enough to implement. There's no need for a permanent deletion. All that's needed is for the moderators to be able to automatically make an edit to the content. That edit would replace the offensive text with something explaining what had happened, and pointing out that the edit history contained the original text.

The moderator presumably deletes in an automated way. All it takes is for there to be a different form of deletion that replaces content with innocuous placeholder text instead of the abusive text.

The problem doesn't happen that often, but it is quite frustrating when it does occur. Deleted answers are only visible to a small fraction of the users, but its the small fraction of the users that visit the site the most. So the impact may be more severe than one might imagine.

As somebody who was personally abused in this way recently, I would have appreciated the feature. However, I don't think it's that big a deal in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Good suggestion, that would leave the audit trail intact whilst still solving the problem.

Comment: Mods _can_ edit deleted posts.

Comment: @Oded - [10Ks too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196731/can-we-nuke-spam-hate-answers-from-orbit-instead-of-just-marking-them-as-delete#comment-621687)

Comment: Don't really agree.  Just get rid of the thing.  What possible value is there to knowing that there was a spammy answer added to the post?  99.99999999999999999% of the time, none.  I doubt that the amount of times you even do need to know is that high (meaning, I'm guessing it's 100%).

Comment: @casperOne If a user is banned/suspended as a result of such actions and appeals the action it's important that a record is kept of the inappropriate posts.  For that reason you can't hard delete the content entirely.

Comment: @casperOne - I know I frequently search against deleted posts to determine if this is a pattern of spam, as well as to find user accounts that need to be deleted. When the community auto-deletes spam via flags, we aren't notified, and we may need to step in to remove everything else a spammer or troll has posted. It also helps for gathering information about patterns of account behavior so that we might be able to take lower-level action. This is why I somewhat resist editing the content of spam that's been deleted, so that I can search for it at a later date.

Comment: @BradLarson These should all be back end reports, not part of the actual page.  They should be given a different flag to indicate "don't show on the main site".  Maybe not hard delete them, but not have them on the main site.

Comment: @casperOne - I wonder if we could make the deleted search operator work on original versions of posts, rather than their final edited state. The final version could be edited safely to obscure the original spam or offensive content. An intermediary state between hard deleted and visible to non-moderators also makes sense.

Comment: Also, David, I'm really sorry for the abuse you've experienced lately. We're trying to deal with this guy as best we can.

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you. It's not bothered me at all as it happens. I've got enough of a thick skin to cope. And I know that I'm a smart alec with a very direct style of commenting. So I'm sure I wind a lot of people up by speaking my mind. Not that it justifies the abuse, but I guess that's why I've been singled out. It's really important that SO remains very easy for people to post questions on. So I guess it's going to be hard to stop things like this altogether. More important to continue letting unregistered and newly registered users post.

Answer (score 12):

Hard deletion doesn't work well with community moderation, it is an irreversible action that cannot be reviewed by the community. There is a hard-deletion like feature available (which only removes revisions, but not entire posts), but SE does not even trusts the moderators with this. Putting hard-deletion in the hands of moderators would be dangerous enough, putting it in the hands of the community would be far too easy to abuse.

I think it would make sense though to collapse deleted answers under certain conditions. For example answers that were removed as spam by a moderator, or also those removed by the community after a certain delay. The answers would still be available after another click, but hidden by default.

Comment: Why not have Community edit the content of a spam post to "Spam deleted"?

Comment: I would do that for every deleted answers. They are already shown after all the non-deleted answers, so collapsing them is not difficult. Even as moderator, I don't need to get them in my face all the times. I just need to know there are deleted answers; if then I need to see what kind of answers have been deleted, I simply click. I would like something like it is done for comments: A link  tells me there are deleted comments, and I see them when I click the link.

Comment: @Manishearth That is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possibly useful leaving these in place for mod reasons, to see what a user previously posted, perhaps?

Either way, as it's just so you don't have to see them anymore as they're offensive/nasty looking/pointless, instead of nuking, why not just hide them with JS and instead have a text link with username/date, something like:
'SPAM/HATE - James - June 12 '03'

The link would still only visible to mods/10K+ users, etc of course, and would be placed wherever the answer would have been placed. It's discreet and one can ignore them, or clicking it to reveal the entire answer/votes/etc, in case you want to see it, for whatever reason.

Though from what I've read I doubt the frequency of this occurrence or severity of the issue is likely to get anything done (soon). Unless you can think of an additional use for such a function - like doing this for all deleted/on hold/whatever answers so older than 6 months?